# Symfony foreach show numbering

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a form show a list of id and emails from database with the code below. I wonder if there anyway to include **numbering** in order instead of using the id.

```
<?php foreach($pager->getResults() as $user): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $user->getId() ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user->getEmail() ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Method Using:
Symfony form,
Pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tested this code, but i think it should work

```
<?php $i = ($pager->getPage()-1)*$pager->getMaxPerPage()+1; ?>
<?php foreach($pager->getResults() as $user): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user->getEmail() ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```